# Top hundred nearest neighbour

Tags: r, k-nn, distance

I have a dataframe with a column called pharmacy number and other columns corresponding to each pharmacy number, there many rows and each row corresponds to pharmacy number. I want to create a dataframe containing the top 100 nearest neighbor of a particular pharmacy number based on the first five numeric columns. The final dataframe should contain the all the columns of the original dataframe of top 100 nearest neighbour of that particular pharmacy number and also the row for that particular pharmacy number .